# Spring RestTemplate.postForEntry, returns 403 error

Tags: spring, resttemplate

I want to communicate with a server in Java area by utilizing RestTemplate class.
But when I access to my server with RestTemplate, it shows just 403(forbidden) error.

my controller code :

```
@Controller(value="homeController")
public class HomeController {

@RequestMapping(value="/test")
public @ResponseBody Map<String, String> test(@RequestParam(value="message", required=false, defaultValue="hell world") String message){

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    map.put("greeting", message);

    return map;
}
```

client side's code:

```
@Test
public void test2(){
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

    MultiValueMap<String, String> map= new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    map.add("message", "test");

    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(map, headers);

    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity( url, request , String.class );
    System.out.println(response.getBody());

}
```

If the code works successfully, console should output "test" word.

**EDIT:**
When I access to the controller, with my web browser, it shows json data correctly.

Now,
How do I fix the code to communicate to server on POST method ?
thanks

Comment: 403 indicates that you are missing authentication. Do you have spring-security on the class path? How do you authenticate your request?

Comment: Thank you really. The problem was spring security. I didn't complete security configuration, and when I remove that source of security, the above problem was solved! Thank you.

Comment: I've answered the question with a quick configuration class for a simple basic authentication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said you're using spring-security, you can simply add a request Interceptor and add authentication. Spring will create a random password if you don't set one; it will be logged in the console so you can simply copy it from there.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.setInterceptors(Collections.singletonList(new BasicAuthorizationInterceptor("username", "yourpassword")));
```

Another (better) option is to configure the authentication yourself. A simple in memory auth would make

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class RestSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();
        http.httpBasic();
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("username").password("yourpassword").roles("ADMIN");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify what kinds of HTTP methods your "test" method handles.
You can do this in `@RequestMapping` annotation this way:

```
@RequestMapping(path="/test", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST}, 
                consumes = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
```

Comment: try to add consumes = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" parameter to @RequestMapping